# Erro no @Scripts.Render("")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Não consigo renderizar bootstrap, scripts e etc, pois meu `@Scripts.Render` e `@Styles.Render` não funciona.

A referência `System.Web.Optmization` está inclusa no projeto.

Veja a imagem com o a referência e os renders com sublinhado em vermelho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Bootsnipp.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Empresa","Index", "Home", new {  area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "HelpPage" }, null)</li>*@
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Solicite um orçamento", "Email", "Email", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />

        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 footerleft ">
                        <div class="logofooter"><img src="~/Images/Logomarca_48_48.jpg" /></div>
                        <p>.</p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i> Endereço - SP Brasil</p> -
                        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Phone (Brasil) : +55 11 99999-8888</p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> E-mail : teste@teste.com.br</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
                        <h6 class="heading7">GENERAL LINKS</h6>
                        <ul class="footer-ul">
                            <li><a href="#"> A Empresa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Política de Pivacidade</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Termos & Condições</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Client Gateway</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Ranking</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Estudos de Casos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
                        <h6 class="heading7">LATEST POST</h6>
                        <div class="post">
                            <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
                            <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
                            <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
                        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/empresa" data-tabs="timeline" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" style="margin-bottom:15px;" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
                            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                                <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/empresa"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/empresa">Facebook</a></blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
                        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.twitter.com" data-tabs="timeline" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" style="margin-bottom:15px;" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
                            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                                <blockquote cite="https://www.twitter.com"><a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
                        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.linkedin.com" data-tabs="timeline" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" style="margin-bottom:15px;" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
                            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                                <blockquote cite="https://www.linkedin.com"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com">Linkedin</a></blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!--footer start from here-->
        <div class="copyright">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - All Rights with empresa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="bottom_ul">
                        <li><a href="#">meudominio.com.br</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About us", "Index", "Sobre", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Faq's</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact us", "Email", "Email", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
                @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Se faltar algum  é porque eu devo ter removido sem querer, pois limpar o nome da empresa para não aparecer, pois não é minha e isso é um teste, para fazer um mostruário.

Comment: Qual é o erro que mostra quando passa o mouse em cima do código sublinhado?

Comment: Imagens não abrem aqui na porque o proxy da empresa bloqueia, tem como colar o código?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o código é: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`

Comment: @jbueno, o erro é: `The name Scripts does not exists in the current context`

Comment: Edita a pergunta e posta o código todo do View, leia mais a respeito em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3635

Comment: Isso é uma solução começada do zero? Ou você modificou alguma coisa?

Comment: Do Zero e Empty, tudo está sendo colocado manualmente, é para aprender mesmo, sugestão sua, @CiganoMorrisonMendez e do Eduardo Pires